Can the question below be posted on Stack Overflow?
I would love to know the answer to this question:

Is there any recognized good design scheme for inter-process
synchronization of desktop applications written in PySide?
That is to say, for example, if there are multiple desktop
applications and real-time synchronization of data status information
between processes is desired.
For example: When an operation is performed on PySide application A
and data A is changed, then PySide application B immediately shows an
update.
In existing product cases, for example, Adobe series of products
(Photoshop, Premierer, AfterEffect). There is a requirement: For the
main task of video editing (Premierer), now a material for a special
effects scene is needed (Premierer only has this material after it is
implemented by AfterEffect). However, AfterEffect needs Photoshop to
assist in making this special effects material. So, this is a task
that can only be completed through communication and collaboration
between three different applications. That is to say, the function is
that after application A updates its content, application B can
immediately obtain the information.
How is this kind of request generally implemented?

I am not sure if my above question can be asked on Stack Overflow directly, so I consult meta first.
If not, any recommended place to do it?

IMO rather than asking "Is there any recognized good design scheme" it would be better to be straightforward and ask "How to perform inter process communication in PySide applications?" If your question is more for general Python that's already asked and answered here.

No, the question as phrased is off-topic for multiple reasons:

Is there any recognized good design scheme for inter-process synchronization of desktop applications written in PySide?

First, you're asking for someone to recommend a design, which is essentially a resource recommendation request.
Second, it's opinion-based (as almost all recommendation questions are). This is underscored by the fact you're asking for a "good" design.
Finally, it's too broad. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. A design scheme for building two apps that can interact needs a lot more focus to its scope if it's going to be on-topic. Instead, you should search for/ask about some specific aspect of how two applications would interact, like how to ensure you don't cause conflicts when writing to a database that is shared between two applications needing to do updates.
For what it's worth, there's never any need or use to ask for a "good" answer or solution to a question on Stack Overflow; it is assumed that people will only provide answers they think are good. In the rare case where there's a reason to provide a known-bad answer, the author generally indicates that (e.g., "this is how to do X, but this is a bad way that cannot be recommended and should be avoided in production code" or something like that).

Your question title "Is this question below could be posted in StackOverflow?".
Yes, you can. But, couple of points to note.
First, it is about proper formatting. You have used code tags to format and discuss your issue. This makes difficult for others the read your question.
Second, have you done any research related to your question? A search term like "python inter-process synchronization" returns some results. Are any of those useful to you? Or any information in those results useful?
Is "inter-process synchronization" is the right term for what you are trying to solve?
You are looking for a technique to use where two Python desktop applications (written using PySide library) communicate with each other in real-time?
Lastly, use proper tags - like "python", "pyside" and other appropriate ones. Specify, the environment you are working in (Windows, Mac, etc.), the versions of Python, and other software you are trying to use.
I feel you need to do further research, include your findings, ask your question and post it normally. The question post should be precise and not include multiple questions.

When people say "can", they generally mean "should I". There is usually little stopping you from hitting the ask question button, but you really shouldn't. You give numerous reasons here why one shouldn't. So kind of strange it starts of with "yes you can".

@Gimby The reasons are for improving the question OP is intending to post. Posting a question is not the issue here. Posting a question and not getting a down vote, is an issue (also, getting an answer). This brings the question that how to make a question which is compliant or acceptable for someone to respond in some way, with useful information, or a useful  answer. Yes, the question can be posted if the OP is clear about the question and with some improvements.

So they can't post "the question below" and the answer should have been "No you can't, unless...".
